# How to get the RabbitMQ Automatic Recovery to work with the C# library?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to build a simple MQTT connection with the RabbitMQ C# library. The connection is working and data is transferred.

Now the problem: If the RabbitMQ-Broker goes down temporarily, neither the publisher, nor the consumer reconnects after it is reachable again.

Based on the [library code](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/c69bf00fb7673f569763e2bf23dbc6bcc1cb462c/projects/RabbitMQ.Client/client/api/ConnectionFactory.cs#L167) of the ConnectionFactory the automatic recovery should be enabled by default.

But even after minutes no connection is listed in the RabbitMQ management interface.

Here is my code so far:

```
RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory _factory;
RabbitMQ.Client.IConnection _connection;
RabbitMQ.Client.IModel _channel;
String _queueName;
EventingBasicConsumer _consumer;
ConcurrentQueue<byte[]> _queue;

try
{
   _factory = new ConnectionFactory { 
      HostName = some.url.com,
      Port = 5671, 
      UserName = guest, 
      Password = guest, 
      VirtualHost = "/",
      AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
      NetworkRecoveryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
      ContinuationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
      RequestedHeartbeat = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
   };

   _connection = _factory.CreateConnection();   
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Error while connection to RabbitMQ Broker: " + e.Message);
    throw new Exception("Could not connect to MQTT Broker");
}
   
_channel = _connection.CreateModel();
_channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchange: "exchangekey", 
                         type: ExchangeType.Topic);

_queueName = _channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName; 

_channel.QueueBind(queue: _queueName,
                   exchange: "exchangekey",
                   routingKey: "routingkey"); 

_consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(mDataChannel);
_consumer.Received += (source, args) =>
{
    _queue.Enqueue(args.Body.ToArray());
};
_channel.BasicConsume(queue: _queueName,
                      autoAck: true,
                      consumer: _consumer);
```

These settings I've only added to be sure they are set correctly and to test different values:

```
      AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
      NetworkRecoveryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
      ContinuationTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
      RequestedHeartbeat = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for using RabbitMQ. I maintain the .NET library. The RabbitMQ .NET library uses the AMQP protocol, not MQTT. Can you please provide a _complete_ set of code I can compile and run? A git repository is ideal. In addition, let me know what version of RabbitMQ you are using and how you are testing this scenario.

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply! Here is a little test app (for Visual Studio Code): https://github.com/avonsyr/rabbitmqtest
It's just the consumer, but the problem is on both side the same: 
1. Start broker (default DockerHub image:    rabbitmq:management)
2. Start test app => connection is listed in the RabbitMQ management interface (and communication works)
3. Restart broker => connection from test app is missing and won't return

Comment: I am busy working on issues for paying RabbitMQ customers, but will give this a try when I can find time. It may be a week or more.

Comment: @LukeBakken something new?

Comment: I can't reproduce what you report. I am _not_ using Docker, but I am running RabbitMQ and your test application on Windows. After I restart RabbitMQ, messages published still reach the consumer just fine.